# Getting the frame of the keyboard at the window level

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to get the coordinates of the frame of the keyboard at window level to be compared with a TableCell to make minor adjustments in scrolling so a selected TextField in the cell wont be behind the keyboard or the header.

However I am having issue getting the x,y coordinates for the keyboard at window level, they simply return 0,0 (origin) which is not true.  Or if it is, is not what I need.

I am using the lines:

```
CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view.window convertRect:_numericKeyboardView.frame toView:nil];
NSLog(@"Keyboard Frame: %f, %f, %f, %f", keyboardFrame.origin.x, keyboardFrame.origin.y, keyboardFrame.size.width, keyboardFrame.size.height);
```

which produces the output(for portrait):

```
Keyboard Frame: 0.000000, 0.000000, 768.000000, 264.000000
```

when it should be more like:

```
Keyboard Frame: 415.000000, 0.000000, 768.000000, 264.000000
```

Any ideas on how to get the correct keyboard coordinates?

Comment: What about when the keyboard is *split in two*?  There are 2 frames then.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by split in two?  I really only need the X coordinate of the keyboard relative to the iphone/ipad screen.

Comment: Under iOS 5+ on the iPad, you can move the keyboard "up" and it splits into two: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/10/12/ios-5-features-split-keyboard-for-ipad/

Comment: This is a custom keyboard made without that functionality.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it this way, you may be sending `convertRect:toView:` to the wrong receiver. Do `[_numericKeyboardView convertRect:_numericKeyboardView.bounds toView:nil];`

Comment: this line returns the result `Keyboard Frame: 0.000000, 416.000000, 1024.000000, 352.000000` which seems right.  I'll test a bit further but I do believe this is it.

Answer (score 2):

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

You need to register for keyboard notification like

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

then

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
}
```

And do not forget to remove self form notification center in your `dealloc` method

Comment: I have a notification for the keyboardWillShow already.  I am attempting to check inside the textFieldDidBeginEditing for my check however.  Your solution returns what seems to be the keyboard in portrait mode even if you are in landscape which obviously makes the values incorrect.   Any solution you know of?

Comment: I had the same problem. I think it is a bug. I checked for interface orientation in my method and inverted width and height if it is landscape. I did not mentioned about it in my answer, because I hoped it is already fixed :)

Comment: if you are still wondering, i found out why the values are inverted.  Its because the origin does not stay in the top left corner of the screen as you rotate the device.  The 0,0 origin moves with the corner its attached to (the upper left in normal portrait and not upside down) so as you turn the device, that corner turns as well.  throwing off all the values

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misleading. It sounds like your "keyboard" is a custom view , not the system keyboard. The question should be "getting the frame of a view in window coordinates". The `convertRect:toView` method will work but you have it backwards.

Change your code to:

```
CGRect keyboardFrame = [_numericKeyboardView convertRect:_numericKeyboardView.bounds 
                                                  toView:self.view.window];
```

Comment: This is incorrect - the rect should be _numericKeyboardView.bounds. A view's *frame* is specified in the coordinate system of its superview. Per UIView docs: the rect parameter is "A rectangle specified in the local coordinate system (bounds) of the receiver." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect:toView: